# Confused about Keyevents GetKeyText method

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I have a very simple application. My goal is to get the character and its code. But When I run this code 
`Key Code :(Unknown keyCode: 0x0)`

I think I missed out something or made a mistake. Could you please help?

```
 String s=String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar());
    int Code=ke.getKeyCode();

   areaInfoAboutKey.append("Key Char  is: ("+s+")'"
           +"\n"+
           "Key Code :("
           +ke.getKeyText(Code)+")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some key codes in Java which are not recognized or implemented in the `KeyEvent` class. This might probably be the reason why you are getting that error. (OR)

You might have written this in `keyTyped()` where the `getKeyCode()` returns `Unknown keycode: (0x0)` Write this in `keyPressed()` to get things done.

Post an SSCCE to get a better help sooner. If you could say what character you have typed, we might be able to answer.

> For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED.

Refer to the docs [getKeyCode() in KeyEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29)

Comment: Thank you.One more thing ..my formatting is correct this time

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell exactly what you are doing based a couple of lines of code.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for a working example of how to use the getKeyText() method.

Comment: see code example in Oracle tutorial How to Write a Key Listener, there is the same code example and tutorial contains quite good description about